# What is the most effective way to stabilize a WaveMaster 2XL?

Tags: equipment

Obviously, the WaveMaster series of standing bags from Century will never be as stable as a ceiling mounted heavy bag with a floor anchor.  However, for many home gyms, the WaveMaster 2XL is a wonderful compromise for those trying to train at home. That said, they do tend to be overly mobile and prone to tip over.  So in short, what are the most effective techniques for stabilizing a WaveMaster 2XL standing bag?

[image: WaveMaster 2XL]

Comment: My only success with these, and perhaps it was a different model, was only letting kids hit it. I found them simply inappropriate for bag work by a strong, reasonably large adult.

Comment: I'm with Dave, I have yet to find a way to stabilize them against a strong force, the things are going to move around the floor. I used to see how far I could move it during exercises.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have a few training tools like these at my school where you have to fill the base up with something to weigh it down. One of the items we have is filled with water, but is smaller than  the equipment you've described. Water, which has a density of 1 g/cm<sup>3</sup>, keeps our equipment weighed down enough that the base doesn't move when you hit the target (which is on a spring). The downside is that water can leak out of it if you're not careful with it or if the container wears out, breaks, or is shoddy.

One of the other larger items we have, similar to the item described in your question, is filled with regular playground sand. It holds down our item pretty well and is sufficient enough that even really hard hits will not knock the thing over (even though it may move back a few inches). It does take some heft to push it around the room if you want to move it, but it works well enough for our purposes.

Another option is concrete which has a density of 2.3 g/cm<sup>3</sup> (give or take, I've found various references citing different values depending on the type of concrete) which is great than water's density. I haven't had experience with filling these types of equipment with concrete, but I do recall from my childhood that the concrete will expand and warp the shape of its container. My dad filled buckets with it for various purposes (which my 10-year-old self thought was heavy to pick up).

Ideally, you should have some method to measure how forceful the hits will be to the training tool to calculate which material is best based on the density and the weight given the volume. It depends on who is hitting the bag and that person's strength. At our school, we have lots of youths who can't move the bag no matter how hard they hit. Some of the adults though can keep moving the bad slowly over time with enough forceful hits. Moving it back isn't too huge an issue.

Comment: Ours were water filled, no issue for me moving them. Sand I've found to be better in my own experience.

Comment: i've heard water and sand is best, if you plan on having to move it a lot, it'll be heavier then one or the other.   if you don't ever have to move it again, concrete is good.

Comment: Following up - water was definitely not stable enough (the wave motion really made it unstable when striking the top half of the target). Sand has been very effective and you only get significant rocking with full power strikes at the top quarter of the target (though even then it's not tipped).

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the filler material listed, we have placed this bag in the corner of the room. Our walls are cinder block so this works rather well.  Of course, this only works with one or two.

Comment: How does that work for roundhouse kicks?

Comment: As we use the ball of the foot for roundhouse kicks, it works just fine.  Plus it REALLY works accuracy.

Comment: For those of us that use our shins for round house type of kicks this would be a less desirable position. :)